# How to set turns (human Vs computer) playing tictactoe on a tkinter gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know how to set turns properly. Based on my code the computer's movement need to be triggered by the player's click on the board. I did it okay human Vs human. The next code is overly cut, but I think we can grasp the general idea.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
    root.resizable(0, 0)

    board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

    def lucky_guess():
        #The computer moves randomly

    def check_winner():
        if board[0] == 'X' and board[1] == 'X' and board[2] == 'X':
            print("Player's won. Game over.")
            # sys.exit()
        # All successful combinations

    def set_movement(square, n):
        global turn
        if board[n] == " " and turn == 'X':
            square["text"] = "X"
            board[n] = "X"
            check_winner()
            messages.config(text="Computer's turn")
            turn = 'O'
        elif turn == 'O':
            lucky_guess()
            check_winner()
            messages.config(text="Player's turn")
            turn = 'X'
        print(board)

    # 9 tiles
    tile_6 = Button(root, text="6", bg='gray', fg='white', 
        height=4, width=8,command=lambda: set_movement(tile_6, 6))
    tile_6.grid(row=0, column=0)
    #Set turns
    choice = random.choice('XO')
    beginning = choice, "'s turn."
    messages.config(text=beginning)
    turn = choice
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest eventually migrating over to having a class structure hold your game state so you can avoid needing global variables...but we'll set that aside for now.

Second, the code listed is incomplete and missing some important variables.

You should have a way or a method of determining if a it is the human's turn or if it is the computer's turn. This method should be called when the game begins (to handle you or the computer going first) and at the end of each turn, after the turn variable has been toggled. If it is the computer's turn... then call your method for picking the computer's square and make the computer's move.